# Git doesn't detect changes in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, github

Me and my friend started developing a web site using a WordPress theme. I uploaded the source code on git hub and started doing changes on the website using the admin dashboard. But whenever git status command is entered in the bash, It says working directory is clean and no changes. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` tracks changes of the source code (or, generally, any files) which lie in the folder where the repository is located. But when you change something in WordPress or other CMS, these changes are typically recorded into database, not filesystem. Only files uploaded by users typically go to the file system, but not configuration settings (like titles and posts).

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer helpful for future readers as well, please consider marking it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).